# In C# regex, how do I optimise matching a sub-sequence of characters

Tags: c#, regex

Given a string input, I want to use C# regex to match part of the character sequence, but in order, from start.

The following inputs will all match:

- `t`
- `tr`
- `tru`
- `true`

The following inputs will not match:

- `tu`
- `tre`
- `tuer`
- `rue`

I figured out a couple of solutions, but I would like a more elegant one, please.

Solution 1:

```
^(t|tr|tru|true|f|fa|fal|fals|false)$
```

Solution 2:

```
^(t(r(u(e)?)?)?|f(a(l(s(e)?)?)?)?)$
```

Comment: Given that that your two solutions work, and that both have beginning of- and end-of-string anchors, your title and first sentence are incorrect: you wish to match one of several strings that are related in a certain way, not substrings thereof.

Comment: The quickest way is this `^t(?:r(?:ue?)?)?$` https://regex101.com/r/ccaJzi/1  The next quickest way is with less characters `^t(r(ue?)?)?$` or even `^(?:f(?:a(?:l(?:se?)?)?)?|t(?:r(?:ue?)?)?)$` These are full blown ternary tries, there is nothing faster.

Answer (score 8):

You use begin/end symbols, so you match whole string either way. Most elegant is this:

```
!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) && ("true".StartsWith(input) || "false".StartsWith(input))
```

Comment: This is very clever, just a little annoying that `"true".StartsWith("")` returns true. Perhaps change your last sentence to something akin to, "If `input` could be empty change the above to...".

Comment: No problem. Here you go.

Answer (score 0):

The most suitable to have is what @eocron mentioned above:

```
"true".StartsWith(inputString) || "false".StartsWith(inputString)
```

If you are searching for regex-based approach:

```
string pattern = @"^t(r(u(e)?)?)?$";
string input = "trueString";
```

Another custom solution tailor-made for this to have a custom implementation like below :

```
static bool StartsWithSequence(string input, string sequence)
    {
        if (input.Length < sequence.Length)
        {
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < sequence.Length; i++)
        {
            if (input[i] != sequence[i])
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

And consume it like below :

```
    string input = "truestring";

        if (StartsWithSequence(input, "t"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Match!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No match.");
        }
```

The above approach compares the first characters of the input string with the characters in the specified sequence. If they match, it will return `true` if not it will return `false`. In this way, you can extend this method to handle longer sequences as needed.

Comment: Saying you prefer another member's solution is fine but there's no need to repeat it in your solution.